# Xray importToSameExecution not working for Cypress Cucumber JSON in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, jira-xray

I'm trying to import Cypress Cucumber JSON results into same Xray execution using "Xray - Test Management for Jira Plugin" in Jenkins pipeline. But in each run Xray is creating a new execution.

**Jenkins Pipeline**

```
stage('Upload xray test results') {
    step([$class: 'XrayImportBuilder', endpointName: '/cucumber', projectKey: 'SPT', testPlanKey: '3081', testExecKey : 'SPT-3082', importToSameExecution: 'true', importFilePath: 'jsonlogs/log.json', importInParallel: 'false', serverInstance: '<<serverInstance>>'])
};
```

**Xray Test Execution**

[image]

**Jenkins Console Log**

[image]

Also I've added Execution ID as a tag in my feature file top level

[image]

Comment: Did my answer helped out? If so, can I kindly ask you to mark as correct? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For historical reasons, the related [cucumber API endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76407756/xray-importtosameexecution-not-working-for-cypress-cucumber-json-in-jenkins-pipe) is a bit different from other ones (i.e., for other report formats), in the sense that it doesn't allow you to specify the Test Execution issue key.. just the report file itself. Thus, those arguments on the pipeline syntax you shared are worthless.

It's possible to update an existing Test Execution though. The cucumber JSON report needs to have the Test Execution issue key as a tag. To have it, add  the Test Execution issue key as a tag before the "Feature: " section, right next to the tag where you have the reference to your "requirement".
Let's say the existing Test Execution issue key is SPT-1000, then your feature needs to be something like:

```
@SPT-1000 @REQ_SPT-3082
Feature: xxx

@TEST_SPT-2882
Scenario: yyy
```

Whenever you run this, the cucumber json will contain the reference to it.. and then whenever you import, Xray will know that it needs to update an existing Test Execution.

Side note: if you use the cucumber multipart endpoint, it will always create a new Test Execution issue though.

The provided link is for Xray server/DC, but even Xray cloud which has a different API, still uses the same logic.